# Titan-all gradle pull fails

Tags: titan

I am pulling the latest titan [on windows as well as ubuntu]

```
compile group: 'com.thinkaurelius.titan', name:'titan-all', version:'0.4.0'
```

and I see the following error :

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
> Could not download artifact 'com.thinkaurelius.titan:titan-core:0.4.0:${titan.classifier}@jar'
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by deleting your `.m2` directory and trying again (apologies for offering the classic solution to all maaven repo related issues).  If that doesn't work, then perhaps you could run a `gradle dependencies` and append the results to your question to see if there's anything interesting happening there.

Comment: I will try it and let you know.Also, I found a similar thread online: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/zbiQnknr25Y but it indicates a workaround that I have been working with for now.

Comment: deleting ~/.gradle didnt help. 'gradle dependencies' is shown here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8v5owkcpb3j2qtd/gradle-dependencies.txt)

Comment: Update: I was able to pull 0.4.1 without any problems.